# Marketing Cloud - Push Notification iOS Title Not Set

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, mobilepush-ios, cordova

Currently I made an application with push notification function from Marketing Cloud.

I used MCCordovaPlugin (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) to get the push notification, and the notification is sent along with the message; except the title is not set and just showing blank gap on the notification panel.

It looked like this :

[image]

I tried to get the log / result for payload sent from Marketing Cloud, and this is the structure that I get :

```
{
"additionalData":{
    "_r":"8bd49617-0793-4ce7-a709-962fd77e43df",
    "coldstart":false,
    "_h":"/jXVNKVf1XSnxdBtPMjsTgAAAAAA",
    "_m":"MToxMTQ6MA",
    "_sid":"SFMC",
    "_mt":1,
    "foreground":true
},
"message":"You may now this sample push message",
"title":"Push Notification Title",
"sound":"default"
}
```

Title and Message already sent through payload, but somehow the title is not set for iOS device and left blank space.

Currently I am also using Salesforce Mobile SDK Plugin (v.5.3.0) for the application authentication, which consists cordova plugin phonegap-plugin-push.

More info :
Cordova version : v.7.0.1

iOS version : v.4.5.4

Kindly advise about this matter. Thank you so much for your help!

Regards,

Comment: We have someone on our push team looking at this from the iOS side now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated :

I update the MCCordovaPlugin to the latest (downloaded from .zip file) from v.1.0.2 to v.1.0.3 and the title is displayed :) Thanks!